# How to use Views 3 API to display custom tables?

Tags: views, database, theming

I have some custom tables in the Drupal Database which are not of any content types. I want to use Views to display the values from the tables on to the website. Is there a way or a module that already provides this functionality? I am using Drupal 7 and Views 3 API.

Comment: There are helpful answers to this question on the following page:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36912/using-views-with-a-custom-table-schema/36921

Answer (score 2):

After lots of research and work, this answer is for people who faced the same problem. The Data module does this for you. This module allows you to adopt a table (created in your Drupal Database and is not a part of any content type, basically a standalone table) and creates a view for that table. The view can be customized. The requirement here is that the table must have a primary key. You can also index this view by creating a content type and using the Views References Module. This will facilitate the indexing of the content in the table and make it show up in search results. Hope this helps.