# Using views with a custom table/schema

Tags: 7, views

I need to set up some views that will pull some data from a custom table I created.  Some views will need to pull content the regular way and from my custom table (where I may query for a particular *nid*, etc.).

How do I do this, or where is a good place to research?

Comment: This article seems to be pretty on point: http://mydons.com/how-to-expose-custom-module-table-to-views-in-drupal/

Comment: That looks like it may be what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your module needs to implement [hook_views_data()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7).

The example given in the hook documentation is for a table defined from the following SQL.

```sql
CREATE TABLE example_table (
  nid INT(11) NOT NULL,
  plain_text_field VARCHAR(32,
  numeric_field INT(11),
  boolean_field INT(1),
  timestamp_field INT(8),
  PRIMARY KEY(nid)
);
```

```
function mymodule_views_data() {
  $data['example_table']['table']['group'] = t('Example table');

  $data['example_table']['table']['base'] = array(
    'field' => 'nid',
    'title' => t('Example table'), 
    'help' => t('Example table contains example content and can be related to nodes.'), 
    'weight' => -10,
  );

  $data['example_table']['table']['join'] = array(
    'node' => array(
      'left_field' => 'nid', 
      'field' => 'nid',
    ),
  );

  $data['example_table']['nid'] = array(
    'title' => t('Example content'), 
    'help' => t('Some example content that references a node.'),
    'relationship' => array(
      'base' => 'node',
      'base field' => 'nid', // The name of the field on the joined table.
      // 'field' => 'nid' -- see hook_views_data_alter(); not needed here.
      'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship', 
      'label' => t('Example node'),
    ),
  );

  $data['example_table']['plain_text_field'] = array(
    'title' => t('Plain text field'), 
    'help' => t('Just a plain text field.'), 
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ), 
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ), 
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ), 
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
    ),
  );

  $data['example_table']['numeric_field'] = array(
    'title' => t('Numeric field'), 
    'help' => t('Just a numeric field.'), 
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ), 
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
    ), 
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
  );

  $data['example_table']['boolean_field'] = array(
    'title' => t('Boolean field'), 
    'help' => t('Just an on/off field.'), 
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_boolean', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ), 
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_boolean_operator',
      'label' => t('Published'),
      'type' => 'yes-no',
      'use equal' => TRUE,
    ), 
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
  );

  $data['example_table']['timestamp_field'] = array(
    'title' => t('Timestamp field'), 
    'help' => t('Just a timestamp field.'), 
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date', 
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ), 
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date',
    ), 
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_date',
    ),
  );

  return $data;
}
```

Comment: This has been an excellent help. However, one of my fields is multivalue, and so I think it must be set up differently -- but how?

Comment: The difference is in the handlers you need to use, and what you use instead of "yes-no"; I cannot tell you which handlers are for a multi-value field, though. Probably it is better as question, if nobody asked it already.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would probably be worth investigating the [Data module](https://www.drupal.org/project/data). This is very powerful, since it allows you to declare a non-Drupal table to Drupal such that it becomes visible in Views as a data source (like "Content", "Taxonomy", etc). You can also declare joins between the non-Drupal table and Drupal entities (so for example if you can stock a nid in your non-Drupal table, then you can declare a join on the nid with any node).

There is also a submodule which allows you to declare your non-Drupal table as an entity, but so far I've not tried that.