# Associating a user with a particular form submit/click

Tags: users, views

In my web site i have created a custom content type Challenge which contains a list of tasks that the user has to do. I have created the custom content type from the CMS itself through admin/structure/content type. I have created a custom form, , and when the user clicks submit i have made a query which insures that the node id of that challenge and the user id is associated in a Challenge table (the code is below). It works fine. Now i need to create a view which shows the challenges accepted by the user, i.e., when the user logs in and clicks on a tab(i am using quicktab) then a view appears which shows the challenges undertaken by the user. Here my code for the query:

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['my_module/form'] = array(
    'title' => t('My form'),
    'page callback' => 'my_module_form',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'description' => t('My form'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function my_module_my_form($form_state) {

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Accept Challenge',
    '#submit' => array('my_module_action'),
    );

  return $form;
}

function my_module_action($form, &$form_state) {

 if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  // Get the nid
   $nid = $node->nid;
    }
 global $user;
 if ( $user->uid ) {
 $query = db_insert('challenges')
    ->fields(array(
    'cid' =>$node->nid,
    'uid' => $user->uid
    ))
    ->execute();
}
```

Well, thats it then. Now how do i create a view to show a user their accepted challenge.

Thanks

Comment: Where to you want show challenge? In node viewing or views?

Comment: inside Node view

Answer (score 0):

1. For node you should load challenges data in your custom module, using next: [hook_node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7) and/or showing next: [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7). See [examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module for it: nodeapi_example.
2. For Views you should define connection with your custom table and node, there nice [example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36912/using-views-with-a-custom-table-schema) for it.
3. For Views also you can use [Data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module.