# table like in admin of custom module

Tags: 7

I have created a custom module that can add an entry into my own created tables. However, I need to display the contents of that table into the admin, a table like view. Like this one in the picture:

[image]

Can you point me to the correct documentation or what is this called?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using views with a custom table/schema](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36912/using-views-with-a-custom-table-schema)

Answer (score 0):

You can create such tables with the [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module.

> You need Views if:
>
> - You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort it differently.
> - You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you want to sort it differently; for example, alphabetically.
> - You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain type.
> - You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display articles the way you - like.
> - You want a way to display a block with the 5 most recent posts of some particular type.
> - You want to provide 'unread forum posts'.
> - You want a monthly archive similar to the typical Movable Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the form of "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month, and displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts for that month.

Comment: Any solution not using an another module? As I was creating a custom module, I want to write one from scratch.

Comment: Sure, Drupal is written in PHP so you can do whatever you need to. I wouldn't recommend it though, Views is the standard solution for this. Everything's already written for you.

Comment: Yes but I want to know what hook does this? Say for example I generated a form using `hook_form`.

Comment: @Clive : Op is talking about fetching records from custom table.. I don't think views will support it.. Correct me if iam wrong..

Comment: @AnilSagar You're wrong ;) [`hook_views_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7). Leandro, there's no single hook that will just make you an HTML table on-screen. There are multiple disciplines involved, and we can't tutor you through those in a single question here I'm afraid. Try breaking your tasks down and attacking each one individually. To get you started, your first task is creating a page containing custom content. See [How should I implement hook_menu()](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62473/) for the answer

Comment: @Clive - I already have those. I already prepared a function that should hold the rendering of records from database, its just that I don't know what to do after I fetch the record from the database.

Comment: @Clive : I am actually talking about using Views UI...Yes, I know using view hooks we can do ;-)

Comment: @LeandroGarcia Ahhh ok :) You're probably looking for [`theme_table()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) in that case?

Comment: If I use that this error would occur `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare theme_table() (previously declared in D:\htdocs\test\includes\theme.inc:1895)...` in my module.admin.inc

Comment: @LeandroGarcia A function can only be named once in PHP (and pretty much all mainstream languages). Have a read through the [themeing guide](https://drupal.org/documentation/theme) to find out how to use theme functions